# Is there a way to email regular, aggregated mercurial changesets reports?

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, tortoisehg

In an effort to boost code reviews, I am looking to send a daily/weekly/monthly/some_regular_interval report of changes from mercurial? I figure that if a person does not have to go and find the changes, but they are instead brought to the person, then that should be a step in the right direction. However, I did not see anything already out there. (We use mercurial with TortoiseHG and Jenkins for the automated build in case any of those tools might help?)

What I am looking for:

**MUST HAVE**

---

- commit message
- list of files that changed

**NICE TO HAVE**

---

- changeset guid
- name of person who did the commit
- some means to see what changed on each file (probably best via a URL or else the email could become overloaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't state what OS you are using.  I am assuming Windows since you are using TortoiseHG.

On Linux (or other UNIX-based OS) you can create a cron that runs once a week/month/whatever.  The following simple script satisfies most of your requirements on my Linux machine:

```
LOG_DATE=`date -d "1 week ago" +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"`
hg log -d ">$LOG_DATE"
```

If you use Mercurial templates you can get exactly what you want.  You can construct a URL using the changeset ID to point to a Mercurial web-server.

Comment: Yes, this is Windows, however we are able to create our own CRON and thought about something like what you are suggesting. I just wanted to see if there was something out there already

Answer (score 0):

Would the [notify extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NotifyExtension) work? You can configure this on a designated master repository so that emails with a summary of the changes (you can customise the template to include the short form of the hash, the user name, the commit message) along with URLs to the individual changesets are sent out to people whenever changese are pushed to the master repository.

Comment: No, I had looked at that, but that notifies on each change. I am looking for an aggregate pull for a regular period (like a week)

Comment: @stephen-rasku's solution would work better for you. The notify extension (which also uses Mercurial templates to present the information you need) could probably serve as a reference :)